# Python share single socket across different modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-sockets

I am trying to establish a socket server and use it across multiple modules to send messages to a client.

I wrote a singleton socket in say `socket_server.py` as below.

```
import socket
class SocketServer:
    _instance=None
    def __init__(self):
        SocketServer.socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        SocketServer.socket.bind(("",5003))
        SocketServer.socket.listen(1)
        SocketServer._instance=self

    def post(self,message):
        SocketServer.socket.send(message)

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():
        if not SocketServer._instance:
            SocketServer()
        return SocketServer._instance
```

I have a module(say module_1.py) where i use the above socket server as

```
from socket_server import SocketServer
socket_server=SocketServer.getInstance()
```

I have one more module ( say module_2.py) where i want to use the same socket server that i created in module_1.py.

```
from socket_server import SocketServer
socket_server=SocketServer.getInstance()
```

But when i try and execute these two scripts simultaneously, i get two different socket server instances.

I want to be able to create a single socket server, use the same instance in both module_1.py and module_2.py to post messages to the port.

Comment: "when i try and execute these two scripts simultaneously" You are running the scripts separately? In two instances of the interpreter? Then you will never get the object for the socket.

Comment: You are trying to bind multiple python processes to a single port. While that is technically possible, I don't think its what you want to do; in general you bind a single process to an IP:PORT socket. I also can't see how binding multiple server processes to the same port will help you in sending messages to a client.

Answer (score 1):

How are you using this object?
At this line `SocketServer.socket.bind(("",5003))` you are binding a port explicitly.
Check ports' list on your server `ss -tpln` is port 5003 already binded?

```
$ ss -tpln
State              Recv-Q             Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                          Peer Address:Port                                                            
LISTEN             0                  50                                   0.0.0.0:46227                              0.0.0.0:*                 users:
LISTEN             0                  1                                    0.0.0.0:5003                               0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("python",pid=23404,fd=3))
```

You can't use one port twice on the same server. You will get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/sock2.py", line 2, in <module>
    sock1 = SocketServer.getInstance()
  File "/home/user/sock.py", line 16, in getInstance
    SocketServer()
  File "/home/user/sock.py", line 6, in __init__
    SocketServer.socket.bind(("",5003))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

But if you try to get one SocketServer's instance from different servers you will always get two separate ports because of different memory space.